# Contact Report - Constituency Summary

Tags: civireport

I unintentionally deleted the Constituency Summary.  I created a new one but the contacts are all grey out and I can't select them.  HELP PLEASE

Comment: Please provide more information like screenshots oslt.

Comment: Even if you delete the Constituent Summary _report instance_, you can create a new one from the Constituent Summary _report template_ - which appears to be what you have done.  Some of the options may be different, although from a quick look, it appears to be the same.  Not sure what you mean by contacts being greyed out - the contact names are all clickable links on one I've just created from the template.